# Symfony2 ACL check always returns FALSE

Tags: symfony, acl, role

### SOLUTION

Well, that's what I get when I use a bit oldish Symfony2 release (2.0-RC6). It seems that there was a bug in `__construct` of `RoleSecurityIdentity` (reported back in December '10).

Instead of `instance of Role` it should be `instance of RoleInstance`.

I should probably close this question...

---

I'm pretty new to whole `ACL` concept in `Symfony2` but I understand basics behind it. Last night I was trying to make next scenario work:

I have 2 user roles (`ROLE_GROUP1`, `ROLE_GROUP2`) and I want to setup **object-level** `ACL` for the one of these groups. If user with `ROLE_GROUP1` is logged in it should put this role into `ACE`, otherwise it should put `ROLE_GROUP2`.

So far I wrote this code (really almost identical to official docs):

```
$role = $this->getRole(); // returns ROLE_GROUP1 role object

$acl_provider = $this->get('security.acl.provider');

$objIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($object); // my object

$acl = $acl_provider->createAcl($objIdentity);

$securityIdentity = new RoleSecurityIdentity($role->getRole()); // Role based identity

$acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
$acl_provider->updateAcl($acl);
```

The way I understand it, this should grant all permissions to users with `ROLE_GROUP1` role. Am I wrong?

To check for permissions I used this code (again, from official docs):

```
$context = $this->get('security.context');

if ( false === $context->isGranted("EDIT", $object) ){
    throw new AccessDeniedException();
}
```

... but it **always** fails (that is throws an exception).

I looked into the ACL tables and everything seemed normal, as far as I could see.

Am I doing something wrong with RoleSecurityIdentity? Is there any way to achieve this scenario?

Any help would be much appreciated!

## EDIT

I just drilled down through the Symfony's code and found out that permission grant fails in `equals` method of `RoleSecurityIdentity`.

```
if (!$sid instanceof RoleSecurityIdentity) {
    return false;
}

/** I ADDED THIS IF CHECK TO SEE WHAT DOES IT COMPARE WITH **/
if ( $this->role->getName() == "ROLE_GROUP1" ){
    die("<pre>" . print_r($sid->getRole(),1) . "</pre><pre>" . print_r($this->role,1) . "</pre><pre>" . print_r($this->role === $sid->getRole(),1) . "</pre>");
}

return $this->role === $sid->getRole();
```

It turns out that `$sid->getRole()` is `string` "**ROLE_GROUP1**" while `$this->role` is `Role` object of **ROLE_GROUP1** role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to mark this question as resolved.

---

### Solution:

Well, that's what I get when I use a bit oldish Symfony2 release (2.0-RC6). It seems that there was a bug in __construct of RoleSecurityIdentity (reported back in December '10).

Instead of instance of Role it should be instance of RoleInstance.

I should probably close this question...